# What is the (approximate) probability that the teacher is through grading before 11:00PM?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

There are 46 students in an elementary statistics class. On the basis of years of experience, the instructor knows that the time needed to grade a randomly chosen first examination paper is a random variable with an expected value of 5 min and a standard deviation of 4 min.

(a) If grading times are independent and the instructor begins grading at 6:50 P.M. and grades continuously, what is the (approximate) probability that he is through grading before the 11:00 P.M. TV news begins?

I was able to do most of the question but I just can't get the final answer...

Here's what I did:

Standard deviation = $\sigma = \sqrt{46}*4$ = 27.129min

mean = $\mu = 46*5$ = 230min  [6:50pm-11:00pm = 4h 10mins = 250 mins]

$Z = [(250-230)/27.129] = 0.7372$

$P(Z<0.7372) =$ ????  I am using the standard normal distribution table which is given to me (and accurate), but I just can't get the correct answer. My table goes up to 2 decimal places, so I looked for 0.73 and it gave me 0.7673 (not the answer). So I tried to round and looked for 0.74 which gave me 0.7704. This was not the correct answer either. Help on how to find the z-score of 0.7372?

Comment: Isn't the standard deviation $4 \times \sqrt{46}$, rather than $\sqrt{4 \times 46}$?

Comment: Yes sorry @actoh thats what i meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In agreement with @AstonMellberg's Comment, you have total required grading
time $T \sim \mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 230,\, \sigma =  27.13)$ and you
seek $P(T \le 250).$ (I think you had an error in writing the formula for
$\sigma$ but not in computing the numerical result.)

Using R statistical software I get $P(T \le 250) \approx 0.7695.$

```
pnorm(250, 230, 27.13)
## 0.769497
```

Standardizing and using normal tables, you will have

$$P(T \le 250) = P\left(\frac{T - \mu}{\sigma} \le \frac{250 - 230}{27.13}\right) = P(Z \le 0.7372) \approx  0.7695,$$
but you will have to round 0.7372 to 0.74 to use the table (without interpolation), so you may
get something like 0.7703. (I think you may have mis-read the normal
table. Look again and leave a Comment if you are still
not getting the answer you want.)

Comment: Oh so 0.7703 would also be correct then (using the table) because that's what I got. ALSO how did you get 0.7695 is what I really wanted to know, how did you interpolate that?

Comment: Hey I did get 0.7703 but as i said above, I'm not sure how you got 0.7695?

Comment: I used R software: `pnorm(0.7372)` returns 0.7694996.  Interpolation would go something like this. In the table 0.73 gives .7673 and 0.74 gives .7704, a difference of .0031. So 0.737 should give about .7673 + .7(.0031) or about .7695.